# Send errors message via email using error_log()

Tags: php, html-email, error-log

The php function error_log() let you send logs to email setting the second param to 1. I do that, but i want to dispay message in html. The code looks like this:

```
error_log($this->_errorMsg, 1, ADMIN_MAIL, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8\r\nFrom: ".MAIL_ERR_FROM."\r\nTo: ".ADMIN_MAIL);
```

Probably i mess something declaring the content type, because i get msg in plain text:

```
<h1>Website Error</h1>
<b>ERRNO:</b><font color='red'>1</font>
...
```

Comment: I just imaged your mailbox after one error in page with many requests. You don't want to do this.

Comment: @Pekka: yes i'm talkin about the native one. its not a framework, i'm workin on a standalone loggin class.

Comment: ah, what do you know, there indeed [is one](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). Sorry, wasn't aware of this

Comment: @Pekka: error_log() is a native PHP function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: @Māris: :) I'm gonna use this class for a particular task, with cronjobs. So i need to know if any errors has encountered, besides i need to access these error logs with my phone everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set up your headers like so:

```
$headers = "From: someone@something.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

note the `content-type` and `mime` headers at the end.

Answer (score 6):

```
error_log("MESSAGE", 1,"email@email.com","From: webmaster@example.com");
```

Answer (score 5):

You should read the comments in the PHP reference for [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), one of the first ones contains an example :

```
error_log("<html><h2>stuff</h2></html>",1,"eat@joe.com","subject  :lunch\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```