# How to create Error log in PHP Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to create Error log in PHP Codeigniter Framework? 
The Error log has Possible to create in localhost ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can enable for localhost. just go to `applications/config/config.php` and add

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
$config['log_path'] = '';// add your path
```

**$config['log_path'] = '' default will be applications/logs dir**

log threshold values :-

```
0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
2 = Debug Messages
3 = Informational Messages
4 = All Messages
```

For more :- [How to do error logging in CodeIgniter (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can enable Error log for both localhost and live server. Please do the step by step procedure as stated bellow:

1. In application > config > config.php change line 183 to `$config['log_threshold'] = 4;`
2. Then run your application and you will get the log file with date as name in applicaiton > logs directory.

If you want to log custom error then use the following syntax:

`log_message('level', 'message')`

Where `level` can be Error, Debug, Info etc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an in built system of logging errors.

This file is `php_errors.log`

This file's locations:

Ubuntu: `/var/log/php_errors.log`
XAMPP (Windows) : `/xampp/php/logs/php_errors.log`

To write to this log file, simply call a function 'error_log'.

e.g. to write a string to this file `error_log('This is a string')`;

OR

CodeIgniter has some error logging functions built in.

```
Make your /application/logs folder writable
In /application/config/config.php set
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
or use a higher number, depending on how much detail you want in your logs
Use log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
```

To send an email you need to extend the core `CI_Exceptions class method log_exceptions()`. You can do this yourself or use this. More info on extending the core here

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html