# CodeIgniter Controller displays blank page when calling parent constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {
      public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
      }
}
```

The code stops executing after calling the parent constructor, without giving absolutely any error messages.  If I echo something before constructor call, it is echoed.If i remove the database from auto load library it will display error message .I have configured correct database details on the database file.Any one please help me?

Comment: enable the error logging in codeigniter, show us the log. we can help. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php

Comment: hi, My index.php has error_reporting(E_ALL);But doen't display any error.Its works fine in Local.The problem only in Server.

Comment: I think the error reporting is disabled for productions. In th eindex.php check the switch(ENVIRONMENT) , set E_ALL for production.

Comment: if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')) {
    switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
             error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

Comment: can you add a index() method in the Home controller and echo something from it?

Comment: public function index()
 {
  echo "sdsdsd";die();
 };But nothing displayed.

Comment: please check the answer and comment.

Comment: if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
  echo "sdsdsd";die();
        parent::__construct();

    }Its displayed  sdsdsd

Comment: You should also check server logs for errors.

Comment: Even the above code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The Question has very few information, anyway I will post this answer so that you can debug your program. If you can give more information I can edit the answer as well.

It sounds like you may have a problem in the `MY_Controller`, to make sure that replace you Home Controller with the following code.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

      public function index(){
         echo "hey I am working";
     }
}
```

If this works, we can come to the conclusion that your `MY_Controller` has an error. In that case we need to see the `MY_Controller` to help further.

Comment: hi,Its not working.$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','form_validation','pagination', 'admin_lib');If i remove  database from this section it will works.

Comment: Can you try removing one by one? then we can find the exact location of cause.

Comment: Identified the problem.I used the dbdriver as mysql. But in my server it was Mysqli. When i changed the  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; in databse.php, it worked fine. Thanks a lot for support

Comment: Glad you fixed it on your own. :)