# Codeigniter Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo base_url('Home_controller/editUser'); ?>',
    data : { user_id : user_id, name : name, position : position, office : office, password : password, reports_to : reports_to, user_type : user_type, status : status },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
        $('#name' + numberId).html(this.name);
        $('#position' + numberId).html(this.position);
        $('#office' + numberId).html(this.office);
        $('#password' + numberId).html(this.password);
        $('#reports_to' + numberId).html(this.reports_to);
        $('#user_type' + numberId).html(this.user_type);
        if(this.status == 1){
            $('#status' + numberId).html("Activated");
        }
        else if(this.status == 0){
            $('#status' + numberId).html("Deactivated");
        }

        $('#edit_user_modal').modal('toggle');
    },
    error : function(errorw){
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

This is my editUser method in my Home_controller

```
public function editUser(){
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $position = $this->input->post('position');
    $office = $this->input->post('office');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $reports_to = $this->input->post('reports_to');
    $user_type = $this->input->post('user_type');
    $status = $this->input->post('status');

    $this->home_model->updateUser($user_id, $name, $position, $office, $password, $reports_to, $user_type, $status);

    $user_details = $this->home_model->getUserDetails($user_id);
    echo json_encode($user_details);
}
```

I used `alert` on all the values on my data and they are all correct. I also checked the url and it is correct. I wonder where did I go wrong? Can someone please help me.

This is the error `jquery-2.2.1.js:9175 POST http://localhost/ppmp/Home_controller/editUser 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I tried to open the url in the error in a new tab and yes it can be found.

I'm stuck here for hours now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's an internal server error. What do the server error logs say?

Comment: This is all I got from the access logs `::1 - - [18/Apr/2016:04:16:21 +0800] "POST /ppmp/Home_controller/editUser HTTP/1.1" 500 1460`

Comment: Check inside your PHP Home_controller, editUser method. If request is coming and try to debug it

Comment: @Mate I edited my post. How can I know if the request is coming coz I can't seem to use `print_r` in my editUser method since I'm using ajax.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php to write log .

Comment: Thank you @Mate I found out what my problem was.

Comment: In your config file update your log threshold to 1 and then try running the script again, any error with your php will be included in the log file. From there you should be able to trace where the problem is

Comment: Great! Add your solution as an answer, or delete your question is it a very particular case

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Problem solved by him self

Answer (score 0):

The problem that i can se, is that in your ajax request you have:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<?php echo base_url('Home_controller/editUser'); ?>',
    data : { user_id : user_id, name : name, position : position, office : office, password : password, reports_to : reports_to, user_type : user_type, status : status },
    dataType : 'json',
```

and in your controller yo have:

```
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $position = $this->input->post('position');
    $office = $this->input->post('office');
```

The problem is that you send a request as a json, but you get the values as a post, you need to change the request from json to normal string.

In the other hand you can get the values in you controller as a:

```
$values = $this->input->get_post($_GET);

$new_format = jason_decode($values);
```

and then proccess the result as you need