# How to change log file extension in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, codeigniter-2

I've seen other posts about Codeigniter error logging ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php)) but my issue is a bit different. For some reason all my log files are being saved as `.php` and I can't find what part of the code is causing this to happen. I've done pretty extensive searching in the repo itself and lots of Googling but can't see anything that's terribly out of the ordinary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have all of those files on your own PC (which I assume you do), try doing a search for all files containing `.php`. Best that I can offer.

Comment: So I can find all of the log files, I just have to mass rename them to remove `.php` from the end. I don't know where in the code that would be happening though because my other Code Igniter apps aren't doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it by `application/config/config.php`. Please find below mention code and set your custom extension.

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Log File Extension
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The default filename extension for log files. The default 'php' allows for
  | protecting the log files via basic scripting, when they are to be stored
  | under a publicly accessible directory.
  |
  | Note: Leaving it blank will default to 'php'.
  |
 */
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
```

You can also generate logs depends on your requirement as describe below.

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Error Logging Threshold
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
  | threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
  |
  | 0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
  | 1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
  | 2 = Debug Messages
  | 3 = Informational Messages
  | 4 = All Messages
  |
  | You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
  |
  |     array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
  |
  | For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
  | your log files will fill up very fast.
  |
 */
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Set custom directory to save your log files.

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Error Logging Directory Path
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
  | application/logs/ directory. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
  |
 */
$config['log_path'] = '';
```

This will be used to set the permissions to log files.

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Log File Permissions
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The file system permissions to be applied on newly created log files.
  |
  | IMPORTANT: This MUST be an integer (no quotes) and you MUST use octal
  |            integer notation (i.e. 0700, 0644, etc.)
 */
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
```

This will be used to set date format for each log entry.

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Date Format for Logs
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
  | codes to set your own date formatting
  |
 */
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `/application/config/config.php` and search for `$config['log_file_extension']`.
Fill the empty value with your favourite extension.

```
| The default filename extension for log files. The default 'php' allows for
| protecting the log files via basic scripting, when they are to be stored
| under a publicly accessible directory.
|
| Note: Leaving it blank will default to 'php'.
```