# 404 not found error show when i try to upload my project on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel, codeigniter-3

I capitalize controller and model class names but after doing all
 these changing
 I faced 404 not found error in code-igniter project when i try to upload my
 project on server please help

config.php

This is my config.php I put every thing , I try

```
$config['base_url']  = '';
```

but nothing happen Please help me

```
[<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function __autoload($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
//$config['base_url']   = '';
$config['base_url'] =  ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ?  "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .=  "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .=  str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the employee guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = 'english';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
*/
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable System Hooks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you would like to use the 'hooks' feature you must enable it by
| setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the employee guide for details.
|
*/
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Extension Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
| native libraries.  For more information please see the employee guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
|
*/
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable Query Strings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
| example.com/who/what/where/
|
| By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
| reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
|
| You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
| example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
|
| Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
| invoke your controllers and its functions:
| example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
|
| Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
| this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
| use segment based URLs.
|
*/
$config['allow_get_array']      = FALSE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/logs/ folder. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['log_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date Format for Logs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
| codes to set your own date formatting
|
*/
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| system/cache/ folder.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['cache_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class or the Session class you
| MUST set an encryption key.  See the employee guide for info.
|
*/
$config['encryption_key'] = 'I6PnEPbQNLslYMj7ChKxDJ2yenuHLkXn';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'        = the name you want for the cookie
| 'sess_expiration'         = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
| 'sess_expire_on_close'    = Whether to cause the session to expire automatically
|   when the browser window is closed
| 'sess_encrypt_cookie'     = Whether to encrypt the cookie
| 'sess_use_database'       = Whether to save the session data to a database
| 'sess_table_name'         = The name of the session database table
| 'sess_match_ip'           = Whether to match the employee's IP address when reading the session data
| 'sess_match_useragent'    = Whether to match the User Agent when reading the session data
| 'sess_time_to_update'     = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
|
*/
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 7200;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross Site Request Forgery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
| checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting employee data, it is strongly
| recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
|
| 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
| 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
| 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
*/


if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))
{

    if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'login') == TRUE || stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'forget_password') == TRUE){
        $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
    }

}
else
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}

//$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Output Compression
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
| the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
| Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
| so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
|
| VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
| means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
| even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
| compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
| by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
|
*/
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Master Time Reference
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Options are 'local' or 'gmt'.  This pref tells the system whether to use
| your server's local time as the master 'now' reference, or convert it to
| GMT.  See the 'date helper' page of the employee guide for information
| regarding date handling.
|
*/
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rewrite PHP Short Tags
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
| can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
| in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
**/
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Reverse Proxy IPs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy IP
| addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
| header in order to properly identify the visitor's IP address.
| Comma-delimited, e.g. '10.0.1.200,10.0.1.201'
|
*/
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';


/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/config.php */
]
```

Databse.php

This is my database php file

```
[

    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    /*
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | This file will contain the settings needed to access your database.
    |
    | For complete instructions please consult the "Database Connection"
    | page of the User Guide.
    |
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    | EXPLANATION OF VARIABLES
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    |   ['hostname'] The hostname of your database server.
    |   ['username'] The username used to connect to the database
    |   ['password'] The password used to connect to the database
    |   ['database'] The name of the database you want to connect to
    |   ['dbdriver'] The database type. ie: mysql.  Currently supported:
                     mysql, mysqli, postgre, odbc, mssql, sqlite, oci8
    |   ['dbprefix'] You can add an optional prefix, which will be added
    |                to the table name when using the  Active Record class
    |   ['pconnect'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether to use a persistent connection
    |   ['db_debug'] TRUE/FALSE - Whether database errors should be displayed.
    |   ['cache_on'] TRUE/FALSE - Enables/disables query caching
    |   ['cachedir'] The path to the folder where cache files should be stored
    |   ['char_set'] The character set used in communicating with the database
    |   ['dbcollat'] The character collation used in communicating with the database
    |
    | The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
    | make active.  By default there is only one group (the "default" group).
    |
    | The $active_record variables lets you determine whether or not to load
    | the active record class
    */
    // The following values will probably need to be changed.
    $db['default']['username'] = "root";
    $db['default']['password'] = "root";
    $db['default']['database'] = "updateinventory";
    // The following values can probably stay the same.
    $db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
    $active_group = "default";
    $active_record = TRUE;
    /* End of file database.php */
    /* Location: ./application/config/database.php */]*
```

My project is running fine on my local machine but when I try to upload on
 live server it shows me an 404 error Please help I try many time to handle it
 but I get same error every time Please help me.

```
**.htaccess**

#--- Uncomment this line for production or testing server
#SetEnv CI_ENV production

#--- Allow remote API access; change "*" to "your-domain.com" for better security
#--- Note: require Headers mod enabled (sudo a2enmod headers)
#Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

#--- URL rewrite
#--- Note: require Headers mod enabled (sudo a2enmod rewrite)
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|install|update)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Please comment this if you have uncommented the above
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is this for? `$config['base_url'] =  ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ?  "https" : "http");` I get that it's checking for HTTPS, but it's only returning a boolean, which when concatenating with a string can't be a productive way of creating a base url

Comment: Also, don't include the [SCRIPT_NAME] which is `index.php`. What happens if you just put your `http://yourdomain.com/`?

Comment: @ourmandave where should i write http://yourdomain.com/ ? please explain it

Comment: It says right above you should put something like, `$config['base_url']  = 'http://example.com/';`. The `index.php` goes in the `$config['index_page'] = '';`.

Comment: You need the trailing `/` too.

Comment: your config file is full of wrong code initialise

Comment: @ourmandave i try as you said $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/'; but nothing happen

Comment: @AnandPandey  please give me some solution how i can handle it, i really need to run project on my server

Comment: show me your servers virtual host also does it reaches to your index php ? Do you have access over apache log ?

Comment: @rajatsaurastri yes it reachs my index.php file but when it goes in this if condition it shows 404 error   {if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
            break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
} }

Comment: is your mod_rewrite is enabled ? Also do you have FollowSymLinks turned on in your apache config ?

Comment: @rajatsaurastri This is my .htacces
#--- Uncomment this line for production or testing server 
SetEnv CI_ENV production 


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|install|update) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
# Please comment this if you have uncommented the above 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA] 
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

In your config file you have to set the base url.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost')
{
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/halal/'; // your localhost link
}
else
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off'){
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://halal.mobidemo.com/'; // your domain url(http)
    }else{
        $config['base_url'] = 'https://halal.mobidemo.com/'; //your domain url(https)
    }   
}
```

I have uploaded my htaccess plz backup your current htaccess and upload this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: Anand
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

No need to change in htaccess, remain as it is above given. Its 100% working in server.

[image]

Comment: yes i change it [if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost')
{
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';// your localhost link
}
else
{
   $config['base_url'] = 'https://mezherhospital.com/';//your domain name]

Comment: i forget to put ; thats why it shows 500 error after write down ; it show again 404 error

Comment: I add htaccess file on above please check it and tell me if it have any error

Comment: hi @MuhammadAhmed: Can you give me your site url?

Comment: Yes sure, mezherhospital.com

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed: its not loading , i have tried it even with index.php but  still not show. Maybe you are not properly configure otherwise the index page show. I want to ask that site running before the modification.

Comment: before this project i am running a html website after that i upload my project and nothing happen, now i am doing some changing to check my .htaccess file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158655/discussion-between-muhammad-ahmed-and-anand-pandey).

Comment: If problem not solved than you have to talk with hosting service

Comment: @AnandPandy how i create error_log file ? can you help me

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php