# 500 internal server error when load model in controller (codeigniter)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I got *500 internal server error* in CodeIgniter. It fine when I don't write `$this->load->model("xxxx");` . I just got error message cause I didn't load my *model* at my *controller*

but when I load my *model*, error 500 happens

this is ajax in CodeIgniter. I've tried not using ajax and I able to insert.

```
 public function add(){
         //data blablabla
         //data blablabla
         //data blablabla
         //data blablabla

         $this->load->model("Training_model"); //when i wirte it, error happen
         $this->Training_model->save($data);

         return response()->json($data);
 }
```

no respond data available

this is might be simple but I can't find the solution. I am really newbie and new into this

---

EDIT DONE , JUST ERROR BUT FINE , I STILL ABLE TO INSERT , thanks for coming

Comment: Where is your model located? in the same directory with controller?

Comment: no , models have own folder

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look into server logfiles for more information.

Comment: done , i can insert , just error but its fine , thanks

Comment: please if you have question answered, don't delete your question so other user that having the same problem could look up the answer from your question

Comment: oke , sorry my bad , i forget that i put my password there , thanks for remind me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change my controller

```
         return response()->json($data);
```

into

```
        $response = $this->curl->simple_get($url);
        $status= json_decode($response, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

please load model in your construction class

```
 ``
 function _construct(){
   $this->load->model("Training_model");
 }
 ``
 ``
  public function add(){
        //data blablabla
        //data blablabla
        //data blablabla
        //data blablabla
  //  $this->load->model("Training_model"); //when i wirte it, error happen
    $this->Training_model->save($data);
    return response()->json($data);
  }
 ``
```

Comment: cant , same respons , 500 , i've tried copying all thing in stackoverflow

Comment: ahh , i can insert data , error 500 just nothing , error 500 but i still able to insert my data , thanks for answer and commend

Comment: 1. load database from config
2. load model construct method

Answer (score 0):

If your model is located in a sub-directory, include the relative path from your models directory. For example, if you have a model located at application/models/blog/Queries.php you’ll load it using:

```
$this->load->model('blog/queries');
```

And this is docs from Codeigniter:

(https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model)

Comment: no , just app/models/mymodel.php , the problem is when i write $this->load->model(); <-this is the problem . after i write that , i got 500

Comment: ahh , i can insert data , error 500 just nothing , error 500 but i still able to insert my data , thanks for answer and comment

Comment: What is the problem cause 500

Comment: that exactly i dont know , and i wanna know

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209807/how-to-do-error-logging-in-codeigniter-php